# Differentiating Stem From Leaf in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I am trying to write program  to detect and display measurements of objects in real time. I have this code thus far (im using an allied vision camera). The problem I am having is that I need to be able to detect/measure the stem of a leaf separately from the leaf itself. However, since I am using contours, it is detected as one single object. I do not know how to differentiate it.

I tried using hierarchies but it doesn't work because the leaf is only a single object  (there is no dividing line between the stem and the leaf). I am thinking that there must be a way that I can classify the leaf from the stem based on the ratio of the height/width, but I don't know how to identify the stem as a separate object. Is there a way to do it based on the distance between the edges  of the contour?

[image]
[image: image 2]

Here is my code:

```
def is_aruco_marker(cnt, pixel_cm_ratio):
    # Define the expected width and height of the ArUco marker
    expected_width_cm = 5.0
    expected_height_cm = 5.0
    tolerance_cm = 0.2  # Room for error

    # Calculate the expected pixel dimensions based on the provided pixel-to-cm ratio
    expected_width_pixels = expected_width_cm * pixel_cm_ratio
    expected_height_pixels = expected_height_cm * pixel_cm_ratio

    # Get the bounding box of the contour
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

    # Check if the contour's dimensions are within the expected range
    is_aruco = (
            abs(w - expected_width_pixels) <= tolerance_cm * pixel_cm_ratio
            and abs(h - expected_height_pixels) <= tolerance_cm * pixel_cm_ratio
    )

    return is_aruco

    def detect_objects(self, frame):
        gray = frame
        mask = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 19, 8)
        # Find contours
        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        cv2.namedWindow('mask', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv2.imshow("mask", mask)

        objects_contours = []
        for cnt in contours:
            area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
            if area > 2000:
                #cnt = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.03*cv2.arclength(cnt, True), True)
                objects_contours.append(cnt)

        return objects_contours

# def main():
# ==============================================================================#



#Load Aruco detector
parameters = cv2.aruco.DetectorParameters()
aruco_dict = cv2.aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(cv2.aruco.DICT_5X5_50)
detector = HomogeneousBgDetector()

# Load the intrinsic and new intrinsic matrices obtained from the calibration script
intrinsic_matrix = np.load('intrinsic.npy')
new_intrinsic_matrix = np.load('intrinsicNew.npy')
dist = np.load('distort.npy')

#object_type = input("Enter the type of object for detection (spinach, peppers, raspberries, lettuce): ")
object_type = 'peppers'

if object_type == 'spinach':
    min_object_width = 1
    min_object_height = 1
    max_object_width = 20
    max_object_height = 20

if object_type == 'peppers':
    min_object_width = 3
    min_object_height = 3
    max_object_width = 50
    max_object_height = 50

if object_type == 'raspberries':
    min_object_width = 0.5
    min_object_height = 0.5
    max_object_width = 5
    max_object_height = 5

if object_type == 'lettuce':
    min_object_width = 1
    min_object_height = 1
    max_object_width = 20
    max_object_height = 20

with Vimba.get_instance() as vimba:
   vimba._startup()
   cam = vimba.get_camera_by_id('DEV_1AB22C014D73')


   if not cam:
       print("No cameras found!")
       exit()


   with cam:
       # Check if camera is connected and initialized
       frame = cam.get_frame()
       if frame.get_status() != FrameStatus.Complete:
           print("Failed to acquire frame!")
           exit()


       # Start continuous acquisition of video frames
       cam.AcquisitionMode.set('Continuous')
       exposure_time = cam.ExposureTime
       exposure_time.set(40000)


       # Wait for some time while frames are being acquired
       time.sleep(5)


       # Stop continuous acquisition
       cam.stop_streaming()


       # Create windows to display the video feed and area measurements
       #cv2.namedWindow('Video Feed', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
       #cv2.resizeWindow('Video Feed', 805, 530)


       while True:
           # Get the latest frame from the camera
           frame = cam.get_frame()


           # Check if the frame is complete before processing it
           if frame.get_status() != FrameStatus.Complete:
               continue


           # Crop the frame to the ROI
           #roi = frame.as_opencv_image()[150:2800, 0:4024]
           frame = frame.as_opencv_image()[100:2700, 100:4024]
           frame = cv2.undistort(frame, intrinsic_matrix, dist, None, new_intrinsic_matrix)
           corners, ids, rejectedImgPoints = aruco.detectMarkers(frame, aruco_dict, parameters=parameters)


           if corners:
               int_corners = np.int0(corners)
               cv2.polylines(frame, int_corners, True, (255,255,255), 10)
               aruco_perimeter = cv2.arcLength(corners[0], True)
               pixel_cm_ratio = aruco_perimeter / 20
               aruco_width_cm = abs(corners[0][0][0][0] - corners[0][0][1][0]) / pixel_cm_ratio
               aruco_height_cm = abs(corners[0][0][0][1] - corners[0][0][3][1]) / pixel_cm_ratio


           contours = detector.detect_objects(frame)


           for cnt in contours:
                rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
                (x,y), (w,h), angle = rect


                object_width = w / pixel_cm_ratio
                object_height = h / pixel_cm_ratio


                #object_area = object_height * object_width

                if (
                    object_height >= min_object_height
                    and object_width >= min_object_width
                    and object_height <= max_object_height
                    and object_width <= max_object_width
                    and not is_aruco_marker(cnt, pixel_cm_ratio)
                ):

                    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
                    box = np.int0(box)


                    cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), 5, (0,0,0),-1)
                    cv2.polylines(frame, [box], True, (0, 0,0), 10)
                    cv2.putText(frame, "Width {} cm".format(round(object_width, 1)), (int(x+10), int(y-20)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (0,0,0), 3)
                    cv2.putText(frame, "Height {} cm".format(round(object_height, 1)), (int(x + 10), int(y + 20)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (0, 0,0), 3)


           # Display the video feed with the contours and area measurements
           cv2.namedWindow('Video Feed', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
           cv2.imshow('Video Feed', frame)

           # Wait for a key press and exit if 'q' is pressed
           key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
           if key == ord('q'):
               break


       # Release the camera and close the windows
       cam.stop_streaming()


   vimba._shutdown()
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Threshold your leaf and clean up with morphology so that only the leaf remains. Then get the contour and apply cv2.minAreaRect to find the rotated bounding box about the leaf. Then rotate the image so that the axes of the rotated rectangle are along x and y. Then measure the thickness of the binarized leaf along the short axis of the rotated rectangle using np.count_nonzero() along each row if the the short dimension of the rotated rectangle is along x. Where thin, it is stem.